# Admin Bar below footer as unstyled list of links

Tags: admin-bar, footer

My admin bar is showing at the bottom as an unstyled list of links, you can see it on [http://advocaateindhoven.net](http://advocaateindhoven.net.)

I'm using WP version 3.2.1. Already tried deactivating every plugin to see if something changed but it didn't.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Help appreciated!

Comment: Also switch theme to default ones Twenty Ten or Eleven, see if something changes, if not check with Firebug or Developer Tool if Admin Bar style are printed

Comment: I have to add that the Admin-bar links are visible at all times, so also for random (logged-out) visitors. Been struggling for a while with this.

Comment: Maybe problem with cache?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by problem with cache?

Answer (score 3):

Have you perhaps copied in the admin bar links into the footer.php file by accident?  At the bottom of footer.php you should see a function call "wp_footer();".

Comment: It's FIXED! I've edited the footer.php manually and deleted the admin-bar lines. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this fixed it for you. Thanks :-)